# onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event)->event.getText() Identifying hint and user text

Tags: android, accessibilityservice

```
 public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {
      case AccessibilityEvent.CONTENT_CHANGE_TYPE_SUBTREE:
                String text = event.getText().toString();
}
```

The current code even return the hint in the event.getText(), How to know whether the text is user entered or hint.

Comment: How sad some random person comments irrelavant answer and when i ask for proper reason he deletes comment and down votes question .stackovetflow find a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we can use getBeforeText() from the event function